# SoftException in Application.cpp:566: Directory "/var/www/html/" is writeable by group

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, users

I installed "SuPHP" yesterday, and whenever, I am restarting "Apache", i am getting below error :-

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                              [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
Invalid command 'suPHP_UserGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

My File Content inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` is :-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
        <Directory /var/www/html>
            suPHP_UserGroup rocky rocky
        </Directory>
    </IfModule>

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Now, My Permission , User, and Group for "/var/www/html" is :-

```
root@rocky:/var/www# ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 rocky rocky 4096 Oct 29 05:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 14 root  root  4096 Oct 29 05:38 ../
drwxr-xr-x  8 rocky rocky 4096 Nov  1 15:29 html/
```

Little information, that i would like to provide.

Earlier `/var/www` content were running under `root`, I changed `owner id` and `Group id` to my normal user group, i.e, `rocky` (user) and `rocky` (group).

So, that :-
1). I don't have to run or browse the directory as root user.
2). When browsing to `http://localhost`, I don't get `Forbidden` error.
3). I don't have to run my editor as root user.

**What i have done ?**

1. I have already checked, the permission and folders, they are `755` and run by user and group `rocky` which is current user (i.e, me) - **No Success**
2. I tried changing the directory back to `root` , `user id` and `group id`. - **No Success**
3. I edited the `suPHP_UserGroup rocky rocky` to `suPHP_UserGroup root root`.

Am i missing anything, my webserver is not working, with below error. kindly help.

```
     * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                              [fail] 
     * The apache2 configtest failed.
    Output of config test was:
    AH00526: Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:
    Invalid command 'suPHP_UserGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
    Action 'configtest' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
```

And Log says :- `SoftException in Application.cpp:566: Directory "/var/www/html/" is writeable by group`

Kindly Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay so to remove a user from a group use the following command in terminal

```
sudo deluser username group
```

then when adding a user to a group you use the following commands:

```
sudo usermod -a -G group username
```

I am not sure what you used to add and create your user as you don't specify in the question so remove the user and then recreate it with the commands I provided if that does not work please show us how you created your user.

Also you could try installing the gnome-system-tool to manage your users and groups visually like so:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

Comment: Yes, and i ate mango yesterday, It was delicious. Completely irrelevant answer.

Comment: Hahaha lol then maybe you should phrase your questions better

Comment: Think, you could write better than that , "`SoftException in Application.cpp:566: Directory “/var/www/html/” is writeable by group`" ,  Ubuntu don't allow "root" user as login. There is 1 default user, which is "rocky" and it is not created, i didn't mention, i created user and failed.

Comment: But the errors you are getting suggests that one or more folders have incorrect permission... That makes it globally writeable

Comment: Yes, and i have all set correctly, permission is 755 as suggested by `suPHP` . I am not sure, what is getting wrong.

Comment: Have you tried maybe moving from the /var/www/html folder to maybe your home folder and then just changing the config of the apache config to that folder?

Comment: and does your var/www/ folder also have 755 permission?

Comment: Yes, it has `755` permission and correctly user id and group set to current user.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed , by removing this irritating `suPHP`. I don't need anymore as it is taking more time to fix and has very less support.

Thanks